# Amazon Web service. Upload a war

Tags: amazon-web-services, scp, pem

I want to deploy a x.war in my tomcat of AWS, but I don't manage upload the file. 
I have written this in my console.
          `scp -i x.pem /home/user/folder/x.war ubuntu@52.16.43.22/folder`

but ubuntu said to me, is not a directory. The directory /folder exist in my instance of AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the : between the server and the local file path

```
scp -i x.pem /home/user/folder/x.war ubuntu@52.16.43.22:/folder
```